# How to extract author names

Tags: titles

I am writing a project report with one of my friend. The problem is, somewhere (e.g., `titlepage`) I need to write all our details, but somewhere I need only names.

Here's what I was trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeindex
\title{}
\author{Author 1 (Registration Number: XXXX, Email: XXXX) \\ \& Author 2 (Registration Number: YYYY, Email: YYYY)}
\begin{document}

% Title page contains the name and other details
\maketitle \clearpage
\section{Introduction}

\section*{Declaration}
% But, here I need only names and registration numbers separately
We, {\it the~authors individually} declare something.
\\
\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of Author 1 (Name only)\\ \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\ (Registration of Author 1) \\ \\ Date \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}

\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of Author 2 (Name only)\\ \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\ (Registration of Author 2) \\ \\ Date \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Is there any automated way to achieve this?

Additionally, I have another question: How can I put dotted lines in signature and dates?

Comment: I added a more sophisticated version ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

Declare two commands like `\FirstAuthor` and `\SecondAuthor`, containing the names of either respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\FirstAuthor}{John Doe}%
\newcommand{\SecondAuthor}{Jane Doe}%
\makeindex
\title{}
\author{\FirstAuthor (Registration Number: XXXX, Email: XXXX) \\ \& \SecondAuthor (Registration Number: YYYY, Email: YYYY)}
\begin{document}

% Title page contains the name and other details
\maketitle \clearpage
\section{Introduction}

\section*{Declaration}
% But, here I need only names and registration numbers separately
We, {\it the~authors individually} declare something.
\\
\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of \FirstAuthor \\ \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\ (Registration of \FirstAuthor) \\ \\ Date \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}

\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of \SecondAuthor \\ \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\ (Registration of \SecondAuthor) \\ \\ Date \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

**Edit** Some other version, just with one `\NameAuthor[]` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%


\newcommand{\NameAuthor}[1][3]{%
\ifnumequal{#1}{1}{%
John Doe}{Jane Doe}%
}%

\makeindex
\title{}
\author{\NameAuthor[1] (Registration Number: XXXX, Email: XXXX) \\ \& \NameAuthor{2} (Registration Number: YYYY, Email: YYYY)}
\begin{document}

% Title page contains the name and other details
\maketitle \clearpage
\section{Introduction}

\section*{Declaration}
% But, here I need only names and registration numbers separately
We, {\it the~authors individually} declare something.
\\
\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of \NameAuthor[1] \\ \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\ (Registration of \NameAuthor[1]) \\ \\ Date \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}

\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of \NameAuthor[2] \\ \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\ (Registration of \NameAuthor[2]) \\ \\ Date \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The first argument of `\NameAuthor` is optional and defaults to `1`, i.e. the first author. I used `\NameAuthor[1]` anyway, to clearify the usage.

---

> **Another, more sophisticated version, using a `*.bib` database and a userdefined citationstyle. The fake author entries can be in any `*.bib` file 
>   used already for the document, as long there is no coincidence with entry key like `author1, author2,...`, but this rather unlikely.**

First define the citationstyle in `authorextract.cbx` file

```
\ProvidesFile{authorextract.cbx}%
\RequireCitationStyle{authoryear}% Change if needed to other style
\newbibmacro{year}{\printfield{year}}%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\namecite}[]{}{\usebibmacro{author}}{}{}%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mailcite}[]{}{\usebibmacro{title}}{}{}%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\regcite}[]{}{\usebibmacro{year}}{}{}%
\endinput%
```

Next the author entries in a `docauthors.bib`:

```
@BOOK{author1,
  author={John Doe},
  volume={XXXX},
  title={\makeatletter johndoe@johndoe.net\makeatother},
  year={XXXX},
  options={skipbib=true},
}



@BOOK{author2,
  author={Jane Doe},
  year={YYYY},
  title={\makeatletter janedoe@janedoe.net\makeatother},
  options={skipbib=true},
}

@BOOK{author3,
  author={Julius Caesar},
  year={QQQQ},
  title={\makeatletter caesar@rulesrome.com\makeatother},
  introduction={Beware the Ides of March},
  options={skipbib=true},
}


@BOOK{author4,
  author={Will Shake},
  year={ZZZZ},
  title={\makeatletter william@globetheater.org\makeatother},
  introduction={I did honestly wrote all plays by myself},
  options={skipbib=true},
}
```

The `skipbib=true` option is important, otherwise all citations would appear in the bibliography --> unwanted here!

Now the `*.tex` code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[citestyle=authorextract,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{docauthors}%


\newrobustcmd{\NameAuthor}[1][4]{%
\namecite{author#1}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\MailAuthor}[1][5]{%
\mailcite{author#1}%
}%
\newrobustcmd{\RegAuthor}[1][6]{%
\regcite{author#1}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\AuthorInformationExtraction}[1][7]{%
\NameAuthor[#1] (Registration Number: \RegAuthor[#1], Email: \MailAuthor[#1])
}%

\newrobustcmd{\AuthorInformation}{%
\AuthorInformationExtraction[1] \\ \& 
\AuthorInformationExtraction[2] \\ \&
\AuthorInformationExtraction[3] \\ \&
\AuthorInformationExtraction[4]%
}%

\makeindex
\title{}
\author{%
\AuthorInformation%
}%
\begin{document}
% Title page contains the name and other details
\maketitle \clearpage
\section{Introduction}

\section*{Declaration}
% But, here I need only names and registration numbers separately
We, {\it the~authors individually} declare something.
\\
\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of \NameAuthor[1] \\ \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\ (Registration of \NameAuthor[1]) \\ \\ Date \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}

\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of \NameAuthor[2] \\ \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\ (Registration of \NameAuthor[2]) \\ \\ Date \\ \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}
\end{minipage}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I 'abused' the `author`, `title` and `year` fields of a `.bib` database to store the `author name`, `mail adress` and a `registration` number respectively. Later on, `\namecite`, `\mailcite` and `\regcite` are used for those cases, see the `authorextract.cbx` for example. Use `\NameAuthor[]` as done in the previous code version and `\AuthorInformation` for the `\author{...}` block.

Compile with

pdflatex foo.tex
biblatex foo 
pdflatex foo.tex

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Is it, what do you expect?

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\authorA{Author 1}  \def\regauthorA{(Registration Number: XXXX, Email: XXXX)}
\def\authorB{Author 2}  \def\regauthorB{(Registration Number: YYYY, Email: YYYY)}

\makeindex
\title{}
\author{\authorA\ \regauthorA \\ \& \authorB\ \regauthorB}
\begin{document}

% Title page contains the name and other details
\maketitle \clearpage
\section{Introduction}

\section*{Declaration}
% But, here I need only names and registration numbers separately
We, {\it the~authors individually} declare something.
\par\bigskip

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of \authorA\ (Name only)\par\bigskip \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\
(Registration of \authorA) \par\bigskip Date \par \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}

\end{minipage}%
\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Signature of \authorB\ (Name only)\par\bigskip \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt} \\
(Registration of \authorB) \par\bigskip Date \par \rule[0em]{15em}{0.5pt}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Note: I did small changes in your code in order to avoid underfull/overfull boxes.